# value 'buster' is invalid for apt::default-release

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I am using: Pop!_OS 18.04 LTS,

when I issue `apt` I get error. please see below.

```
sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
E: The value 'buster' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
sudo apt dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
E: The value 'buster' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
sudo apt autoremove --purge
Reading package lists... Done
E: The value 'buster' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
sudo apt install synaptic
Reading package lists... Done
E: The value 'buster' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Pop!_Tech](https://system76.com/pop/tech)

> Pop!_OS is built on Ubuntu and its repositories. We follow the Ubuntu version numbers and release cycle.

"Buster" is a Debian release name, not an Ubuntu one.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/defaultrelease

sudo apt update
```

solved the problems.